# Computer architecture - paging

Tags: paging, cpu-architecture, tlb

assume that 
- accessing and searching the TLB takes 5ns 
- transferring the data from the tlb into a register takes 10 ns 
- updating a record in the TLB takes 15 ns 
- accessing and searching the pt takes 50ns 
- transfering the data from the PT into a register takes 70ns
- the TLB hit ratio is 0,6.
How many nanoseconds are needed on average to perform all the TLB and PT operations needed to compute the physical address for a given virtual address(assuming that all referenced pages are in main memory).

Comment: You have to calculate the translation latency for two case: in case of a TLB hit and in case of a TLB miss. Then you can calculate the "average" (or more like the [expected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) translation latency because you are given the TLB hit ratio). I think you can assume that there is no prefetching and that everything happens serially.

Comment: The part "assuming that all referenced pages are in main memory" means that page faults can never occur. So that simplifies the problem.

Comment: You should remove the irrelevant `pt` and `buffer` tags by editing the question. Otherwise, you may get downvoted.